# What format does the internal disk need to be in to to install Big Sur from USB?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, big-sur

I have a 2016 128Gb MacBook Pro and am trying to install Big Sur from a USB. I have deleted both the Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - data using Disk Utility in recovery mode.

In Disk Utility, under the `Internal` header, I have a main disk called Apple SSD AP0128J Media (GUID Partition Map). Nested under that I have a Container disk2.

When I am in recovery mode, I have the option to "Reinstall macOS Big Sur" from my USB. However, when asked which disk I want to install it on, there isn't the option to install it onto the HD disk - only the USB. Therefore, I think that the HD disk isn't formatted correctly.

How should I format the HD in Disk Utility so that I can install Big Sur on to it?

Comment: You can try formatting as APFS as that is the (new) native Apple file system. It is odd, however, that the installer didn't offer to install anyway, but it has been a while since I have installed from a USB to an unformatted disk...

Comment: When you are in the disk utility of your USB installer, you select the ssd physical cmd+2 if not listed, then you choise Erase and partition scheme guid, format Apfs and  name you want. You valid and quit disk utility. Your installation will be done after.